trying to send mail with smtp is not working
SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted
    with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com") as connection:
        connection.starttls()
        connection.login(user=my_gmail, password=my_password)
        connection.sendmail(from_addr=my_gmail, to_addrs=reciver, msg=f"subject: My love for you.\n\n {message}")

expecting it to send mail to reciver
